# Converting normal datetime to a time zone in sql server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, timezone

I have a column which is of `datetime` data type. It contains few entries. So while getting the value from the select statement I want to output with Time zone. Please help me

for example

```
2007-05-08 12:35:29.1234567 +05:30 (GMT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to `dtaetimeoffset` like

```
select CAST(dt as datetimeoffset)  from test
```

EDIT:

you can then use `SWITCHOFFSET` to get into the specified timezone. For your example

```
select switchoffset(CAST(dt as datetimeoffset),'+05:30')  from test
```

Results in `2011-11-24 23:26:30.0600000 +05:30`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is giving me the output as

2011-11-16 14:58:13.1730000 +00:00

in the end it is giving me 00:00 and the actual one

Comment: Thanks for your ans. It has partly solved my problem the only question remains is How to get ('+5:30') automatically. As i have one more column which has locations like 'Paris', 'London'