# How can I convert a Nagios timestamp to datetime?

Tags: sql, t-sql, type-conversion

i have got an sql server 2008. i get a icinga/nagios timestamp for server downtimes.

It is exactly in this format `Wed Apr 10 14:45:00 CEST 2013`.

Thats a wierd format for me. I want to cast/convert it into t-sql datetime - but dont know how.

Comment: Are the timestamps always CEST, or can there be other time zones too? And how do you get the data into SQL Server, it may be easier to convert it outside the database into the [ISO 8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) using a language with good text parsing and/or date library support, and then load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **[CEST](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/cest.html) is +02:00**

```
select
CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(WEEKDAY, 
switchoffset(CAST(date_column_name as datetimeoffset),'+02:00')), 100)
+ ' ' +
CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MM,  
switchoffset(CAST(date_column_name as datetimeoffset),'+02:00')), 100)
+ ' ' +
DATENAME(DAY, 
switchoffset(CAST(date_column_name as datetimeoffset),'+02:00'))
+ ' ' +
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),
switchoffset(CAST(date_column_name as datetimeoffset),'+02:00'), 108)
+ ' CEST ' +
DATENAME(YEAR, 
switchoffset(CAST(date_column_name as datetimeoffset),'+02:00'))
from adm_co_users
```

I am first **[Converting the Date to CEST Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256892/converting-normal-datetime-to-a-time-zone-in-sql-server-2008)** and then **extracting** the **date** as required.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select Cast( 
-- Day
substring(@sTimestamp, 9, 2) + ' ' 
-- Month
+ substring(@sTimestamp, 5, 3)  + ' '
-- Year
+ substring(@sTimestamp, 26, 4) + ' '
-- Time
+ substring(@sTimestamp, 12, 8) + ' '
as datetime)
```

This doesn't do anything for the timezone though - I suggest you put something in for that.

Comment: +1 Experience counts. But i am newbie in `SQL` hence the **layman method**. how to do a lot of Search to get the answer. but your answer is the best.